react-infinite-scroll-component works with MUI Autocomplete
Flowing is my component in react complied with js, I have configured hasMore and next correcly with InfiniteScroll. Once i Scroll with the MUI Auto complete scrollableTarget does not get any hit i think the error is with the scrollable traget
<InfiniteScroll
      dataLength={patientData.length}
      next={getMorePatients}
      hasMore={hasMore}
      endMessage={<h4>End of List</h4>}
      scrollableTarget="patient-auto-complete"
    >
      <Autocomplete
        id="patient-auto-complete"
        options={patientData}
        value={patient}
        filterOptions={filterOptionsPatientList}
        onChange={handlePatientChange}
        renderOption={(props, option) => {
          return (
            <li {...props} key={option.id} value={option.id}>
              {(option.firstName === option.lastName
                ? option.firstName
                : option.firstName + " " + option.lastName
              ).replace(null, "")}
            </li>
          );
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Patient" />}
        disabled={formMode === "edit_meeting"}
        sx={{
          borderBottom: errorPatient ? 2 : 0,
          borderColor: errorPatient ? "error.main" : null,
        }}
      />
    </InfiniteScroll>;

